# Shared connection string between multiple projects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, connection-string

I have multiple projects being hosted in IIS. These all share a database, which is called using EF6. I want to be able to use a shared connection string config file which I can reference from each of the other projects' web.config. This way, I'm able to manage any chances to the connection string from a single location. From what I've found online, I'm trying to accomplish this through a Virtual Directory and the configSource attribute for the connectionString.

IIS structure

-VirtualDirectory (mapped to /DbConfigFile)
-WebApp 1
-WebApp 2
-WebApp 3

WebApps' Web.config connectionString sections
    `<connectionStrings configSource="/DbConfigFile/testDB.config"></connectionStrings>`

The external config file (testDB.config) containing the connectionString needed by all applications.
    `<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestDB.csdl|res://*/TestDB.ssdl|res://*/TestDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=TestDB;initial catalog=VBODashboard;persist security info=True;user id=Test;password=Test;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>`

I've tried various paths in the configSource attribute with no luck (~/DbConfigFile/testDB.config, testDB.config). How would I access this file? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why not store the connection string in an environment variable? Or in a configuration database? Or in any custom configuration file? You don't have to stick to the .config connectionStrings for storing this information: it's just a string!

Comment: Check this blog post [here](http://www.raghurana.com/sharing-common-connection-strings-between-projects). 
You can use "Add as a link" option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with one of mason's suggestions and creating a custom configuration file. That let me to research finding out that a connection string can be specified through code when initializing the context. I then navigated through the XML file through code and extracted the connection string value. :

```
public partial class TestDBEntities : DbContext
{
 public TestDBEntities()
  : base(<calling code to get connection string> , true)
    {
    }
     ...
}
```